# Using Android SDK in a test project (`Android.Content.Intent`)

Tags: android, unit-testing, module, gradle

I have a test module in my gradle project and I'm trying to get the following code to compile:

```
@Test
public void ifUserIsNotLoggedInTheyShouldBePrompted(){
    MyOpportunitiesActivity_ activity = Robolectric
            .buildActivity(MyOpportunitiesActivity_.class)
            .create()
            .get();

    Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(activity.getBaseContext(), LoginActivity_.class);
    assertThat(Robolectric.shadowOf(activity).getNextStartedActivity()).isEqualTo(expectedIntent);
}
```

My `build.gradle` file imports my android app and `com.android.support:support-v4:19.01`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: what are you trying to do here?